# FFmpeg outputs empty file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, 4k-resolution

I'm trying to cut 4K@60fps video using **FFMpeg 3.2.4 (x64)** for Windows without re-encoding:

```
ffmpeg -i D:/video/qc_01.mp4 -c copy -ss 00:27:00 -to 00:56:00 D:/video/01.mp4
```

I get almost empty file (290 bytes) and it outputs this:

```
D:\video>ffmpeg -i D:/video/qc_01.mp4 -c copy -ss 00:27:00 -to 00:56:00 D:/video/01.mp4 > output.txt
ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r
--enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-l
ibmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy -
-enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable
-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/video/qc_01.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2017-04-15T00:48:17.000000Z
    date            : 2017
  Duration: 00:12:19.26, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 48108 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt470m), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 47902 kb/s, 59.38 fps, 60 tbr, 60k tbn, 120 tbc
 (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-04-15T00:48:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 196 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-04-15T00:48:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'D:/video/01.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    date            : 2017
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt470m), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 47902 kb/s, 59.38 fps, 60 tbr, 60k
 tbn, 60k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-04-15T00:48:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, 196 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-04-15T00:48:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown

D:\video>
```

Comment: `-c` is an output flag and `-ss` is an input flag so they are in the wrong order. Try: `ffmpeg -i D:/video/qc_01.mp4 -ss 00:27:00 -c copy -a copy -to 00:56:00 D:/video/01.mp4`

Comment: Alternatively, try `ffmpeg -i D:/video/qc_01.mp4 -ss 00:27:00 -c copy -a copy -t 29 D:/video/01.mp4` which uses a duration instead of a stop time

Comment: Nope. It won't recognize option "a" and after removing it does the same for both commands.

Comment: try `-acodec copy` instead

Comment: doh, ignore the `-a` and `-acodec` entirely. My bad. I somehow misread `-c` as `-v`... so thought you were only copying the video stream....

Comment: Nope. Still the same. Tried both x64 and x32 version of FFmpeg. :-/

Comment: what happens if you remove `-to` entirely? does it copy from 00:27:00 to the end?

Comment: Nope. Gives exactly the same result. But it starts when I remove `-ss`.

Comment: and if you put in `-t` or `-to` without `-ss`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57333/discussion-between-shevek-and-klaatu-verata-necto).

Comment: @Shevek `-ss` can be used as an output option too. Also, `-v` and `-a` do not refer to video or audio streams.

Answer (score 1):

The video is 12 minutes long. Position is passed incorrectly.
Passing from second 27 to second 56:

```
ffmpeg -i D:/video/qc_01.mp4 -ss 00:00:27 -to 00:00:56 -c copy D:/video/01.mp4
```